# CryptProtectData in one exe and CryptUnprotectData in different exe on same machine and same user credentials fails - Error code 998

Tags: c++, winapi

When both CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData done in same exe like below code, it works.
When we run CryptProtectData first by commentting CryptUnprotectData and then again run CryptUnprotectData by commenting CryptProtectData , the decryption fails with error code -
ERROR_NOACCESS
998 (0x3E6)
Invalid access to memory location.

```
#pragma once
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

int main()
{

 std::string username = "abcxyzabc";
 std::string fileName = "./ConfigInfoNew.dat";
 //==================Encryption=========================
 bool retvalue = true;
    
 std::ofstream encryptedfile(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
 DATA_BLOB dataout;
 char* ca = new char[username.size() + 1];
 std::copy(username.begin(), username.end(), ca);
 ca[username.size()] = '\0';
 byte* pbdatainput = (byte*)ca;
 dword cbdatainput = strlen((char*)pbdatainput) + 1;
 DATA_BLOB datain;
 datain.pbdata = pbdatainput;
 datain.cbdata = cbdatainput;
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------
 //  begin protect phase.
 if (cryptprotectdata(&datain,
    null, // a description string.
    null,                               // optional entropy not used.
    null,                               // reserved.
    null,                      // pass a promptstruct.
    CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE,//unsigned int(0),
    &dataout))
 {
    std::cout << (char*)(dataout.pbdata) << std::endl;
    encryptedfile.write((char*)&dataout.cbdata, sizeof(dword));
    encryptedfile.write((char*)&dataout.pbdata, sizeof(dataout.pbdata));
    dword errcode = getlasterror();
    std::cout << " encrypt success code ---" + std::to_string(errcode) + "---" << std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
    dword errcode = getlasterror();
    std::cout << " encrypt failed code ---" + std::to_string(errcode) + "---" << std::endl;
 }
 encryptedfile.close();
 //===============Decryption====================
 std::ifstream decryptFile(fileName, std::ios::in);
 if (decryptFile.is_open())
 {
     {
         DATA_BLOB pEncryptedData;
         decryptFile.read((char*)&pEncryptedData.cbData, sizeof(DWORD));
         pEncryptedData.pbData = new BYTE[pEncryptedData.cbData];
         decryptFile.read((char*)&pEncryptedData.pbData, sizeof(pEncryptedData.pbData));
         DATA_BLOB DataVerify;
         if (CryptUnprotectData(
             &pEncryptedData,
             NULL,
             NULL,                 // Optional entropy
             NULL,                 // Reserved
             NULL,        // Optional PromptStruct
             CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE, //unsigned int(0),
             &DataVerify))
         {
             std::cout << (char*)(DataVerify.pbData) << std::endl;
             DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
             std::cout << " Decrypt Success code ---" + std::to_string(errCode) + "---" << std::endl;
         }
         else
         {
             LocalFree(pEncryptedData.pbData);
             LocalFree(DataVerify.pbData);
             DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
             std::cout << " Decrypt failed code ---" + std::to_string(errCode) + "---" << std::endl;
             return false;
         }
         LocalFree(pEncryptedData.pbData);
         LocalFree(DataVerify.pbData);
     }
 }
 decryptFile.close();
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Invalid access to memory location" very strongly suggests that you stored a pointer in your file instead of the actual data.  Pointer values aren't meaningful across processes.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(dataout.pbdata)` and `sizeof(pEncryptedData.pbData)` is useless, it's the size of a pointer, not the size of the data it points to.  Use `dataout.cbdata` and `pEncryptedData.cbData` instead.  And why do you have two difference types, `data_blob` and `DATA_BLOB` ?

Comment: Kindly refrain from posting fantasy code. This code has absolutely no chance to compile on its own. There is no inclusion of the appropriate windows headers, and even if there were, `cryptprotectdata` is fictitious, as is `data_blob`, `byte`, `dword`, etc. If you have a proper [mcve], post that. If you don't, then make one.

Comment: Broken error handling, you must call GetLastError() *immediately* after the failing winapi call.  Right now it reports failure for the bad LocalFree calls.  Memory allocated with new[] requires delete[], don't call LocalFree when the function failed.

Comment: Quoting from the [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4610476/): *"Extensive Debugging Skills"*. Given that you posted this (fantasy) code without ever running it under a debugger, that seems like a questionable self-assessment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the question that can run and debugged.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing the *pointer* to the encrypted data into your file, instead of writing the actual encrypted data.  So it makes sense why decryption works when performed in the same process as the encryption, but not in a separate process.

You need to change this:

```
encryptedfile.write((char*)&dataout.pbdata, sizeof(dataout.pbdata));
...
decryptFile.read((char*)&pEncryptedData.pbData, sizeof(pEncryptedData.pbData));
```

To this instead:

```
encryptedfile.write((char*)dataout.pbdata, dataout.cbdata);
...
decryptFile.read((char*)pEncryptedData.pbData, pEncryptedData.cbData);
```

---

That being said, your code can be simplified a little bit:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

int main()
{
    std::string username = "abcxyzabc";
    std::string fileName = "./ConfigInfoNew.dat";

    //==================Encryption=========================
    std::ofstream encryptedfile(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (encryptedfile.is_open())
    {
        DATA_BLOB datain, dataout;

        datain.pbdata = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(username.data()); // or: reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(const_cast<char*>(username.c_str()))
        datain.cbdata = username.size() + 1;

        if (!CryptProtectData(&datain,
            nullptr, // a description string.
            nullptr, // optional entropy not used.
            nullptr, // reserved.
            nullptr, // pass a promptstruct.
            CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            &dataout))
        {
            DWORD errcode = GetLastError();
            std::cout << " encrypt failed code ---" + std::to_string(errcode) + "---" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dataout.pbdata), dataout.cbdata);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        if (!(encryptedfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataout.cbdata), sizeof(dataout.cbdata)) &&
              encryptedfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dataout.pbdata), dataout.cbdata)))
        {
            std::cout << " failed to write to encrypted file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        encryptedfile.close();
        std::cout << " encrypt success" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " failed to create encrypted file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //===============Decryption====================
    std::ifstream decryptFile(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (decryptFile.is_open())
    {
        DATA_BLOB EncryptedData, DataVerify;

        if (!decryptFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&EncryptedData.cbData), sizeof(EncryptedData.cbData)))
        {
            std::cout << " failed to read from encrypted file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::vector<BYTE> buffer(EncryptedData.cbData);
        EncryptedData.pbData = buffer.data();

        if (!decryptFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(EncryptedData.pbData), EncryptedData.cbData))
        {
            std::cout << " failed to read from encrypted file" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        if (!CryptUnprotectData(
            &EncryptedData,
            nullptr,
            nullptr, // Optional entropy
            nullptr, // Reserved
            nullptr, // Optional PromptStruct
            CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            &DataVerify))
        {
            DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
            std::cout << " Decrypt failed code ---" + std::to_string(errCode) + "---" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(DataVerify.pbData), DataVerify.cbData);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << " decrypt success" << std::endl;

        LocalFree(DataVerify.pbData);
        decryptFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " failed to open encrypted file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Remy and Ben, As I was storing the pointers insterad of the data, it is working only for the same process but not across processes. After storing the data correctly, it worked as mentioned above code.